# vkCmdBlitImage to Frambuffer, then draw UI: UI is blinking

Tags: vulkan

I'm making a Vulkan (LWJGL) app that will draw directly to framebuffer images. No vertex or fragment shader, just some compute shader to build an image, which I blit directly into a FrameBuffer image. It's working fine.

Now I try to render an UI (imgui) on top of that, but I think I have some synchronization trouble : the UI is blinking sometimes (the blit is maybe not yet finished ?). The render would be perfect for some seconds, but sooner or later, the UI disappears during maybe one frame. I only build the render pass once, I don't record the command buffers more than once for this test, so I think the problem happen when I record the command buffer.

Maybe the problem is that the vkCmdBlitImage is still running when the UI starts to draw ?
I tried to add some barriers, between the blit and the UI render, but the problem is still here.

I think I really miss something, so I'm requesting your help. I put here the code I think relevant,  but don't hesitate to ask more code.

The record of the CommandBuffer:

```
for (int i = 0; i < commandBuffers.size(); i++)
{
    RenderCommandBuffer commandBuffer = commandBuffers.get(i);
    ImageView imageView = configuration.imageViewManager.getImageViews().get(i);

    commandBuffer.startCommand();

    copyPixelBufferToFB(commandBuffer, imageView);

    commandBuffer.startRenderPass();

    imGui.drawFrame(commandBuffer.getVkCommandBuffer());

    commandBuffer.endRenderPass();
    commandBuffer.endCommand();
}
```

The copyPixelBufferToFB method:

```
Extent2D extent = context.swapChainManager.getExtent();
ImageView dstImageView = context.imageViewManager.getImageViews().get(commandBuffer.id);

// Intend to blit from this image, set the layout accordingly
// Prepare transfer from Image to Frambuffer
ImageBarrier barrier = new ImageBarrier(VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COMPUTE_SHADER_BIT,
        VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT);
barrier.addImageBarrier(srcImage, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL,
        VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_READ_BIT);
barrier.addImageBarrier(dstImageView.getImageId(), dstImageView.getImageFormat(), 1, 0,
        VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL, 0, VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT);

barrier.execute(commandBuffer.getVkCommandBuffer());

long bltSrcImage = srcImage.getId();
long bltDstImage = dstImageView.getImageId();

VkImageBlit.Buffer region = VkImageBlit.calloc(1);
region.srcSubresource().aspectMask(VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT);
region.srcSubresource().mipLevel(0);
region.srcSubresource().baseArrayLayer(0);
region.srcSubresource().layerCount(1);
region.srcOffsets(0).x(0);
region.srcOffsets(0).y(0);
region.srcOffsets(0).z(0);
region.srcOffsets(1).x(srcImage.getWidth());
region.srcOffsets(1).y(srcImage.getHeight());
region.srcOffsets(1).z(1);
region.dstSubresource().aspectMask(VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT);
region.dstSubresource().mipLevel(0);
region.dstSubresource().baseArrayLayer(0);
region.dstSubresource().layerCount(1);
region.dstOffsets(0).x(0);
region.dstOffsets(0).y(0);
region.dstOffsets(0).z(0);
region.dstOffsets(1).x(extent.getWidth());
region.dstOffsets(1).y(extent.getHeight());
region.dstOffsets(1).z(1);

vkCmdBlitImage(commandBuffer.getVkCommandBuffer(), bltSrcImage,
        VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL, bltDstImage,
        VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL, region, VK_FILTER_NEAREST);


// Change layout again before render pass.
ImageBarrier barrierEnd = new ImageBarrier(VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT,
        VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT);
barrierEnd.addImageBarrier(srcImage, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL, VK_ACCESS_SHADER_WRITE_BIT);
barrierEnd.addImageBarrier(dstImageView.getImageId(), dstImageView.getImageFormat(), 1,
        VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL,
        VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT, VK_ACCESS_SHADER_WRITE_BIT);

barrierEnd.execute(commandBuffer.getVkCommandBuffer());
```

How I submit the CommandBuffer, something like that:

```
bWaitSemaphores.put(waitSemaphore.getId());
bwaitStage.put(VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT);
pCommandBuffers.put(commandBuffer.getVkCommandBuffer());

submitInfo = VkSubmitInfo.calloc();
submitInfo.sType(VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO);
submitInfo.waitSemaphoreCount(bWaitSemaphores.size());
submitInfo.pWaitSemaphores(bWaitSemaphores);
submitInfo.pWaitDstStageMask(bwaitStage);
submitInfo.pCommandBuffers(pCommandBuffers);

[...]
vkQueueSubmit(queue, submitInfo, VK_NULL_HANDLE);
```

The creation of the RenderPass:

```
VkAttachmentDescription colorAttachment = VkAttachmentDescription.calloc();
colorAttachment.format(context.swapChainManager.getColorDomain().getColorFormat());
colorAttachment.samples(VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT);
colorAttachment.loadOp(VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_LOAD);
colorAttachment.storeOp(VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE);
colorAttachment.stencilLoadOp(VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE);
colorAttachment.stencilStoreOp(VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE);
colorAttachment.initialLayout(VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL);
colorAttachment.finalLayout(VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR);

VkAttachmentReference.Buffer colorAttachmentRef = VkAttachmentReference.calloc(1);
colorAttachmentRef.attachment(0);
colorAttachmentRef.layout(VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL);

VkSubpassDescription.Buffer subpass = VkSubpassDescription.calloc(1);
subpass.pipelineBindPoint(VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS);
subpass.colorAttachmentCount(1);
subpass.pColorAttachments(colorAttachmentRef);

VkSubpassDependency.Buffer dependency = VkSubpassDependency.calloc(1);
dependency.srcSubpass(VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL);
dependency.dstSubpass(0);
dependency.srcStageMask(VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT);
dependency.dstStageMask(VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT);
dependency.srcAccessMask(0);
dependency.dstAccessMask(
        VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT | VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT);

int attachmentCount = 1;
VkAttachmentDescription.Buffer attachments = VkAttachmentDescription
        .calloc(attachmentCount);
attachments.put(colorAttachment);
attachments.flip();

VkRenderPassCreateInfo renderPassInfo = VkRenderPassCreateInfo.calloc();
renderPassInfo.sType(VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_CREATE_INFO);
renderPassInfo.pAttachments(attachments);
renderPassInfo.pSubpasses(subpass);
renderPassInfo.pDependencies(dependency);

long[] aRenderPass = new long[1];
if (vkCreateRenderPass(logicalDevice.getVkDevice(), renderPassInfo, null,
        aRenderPass) != VK_SUCCESS)
{
    throw new AssertionError("Failed to create render pass!");
}
renderPass = aRenderPass[0];
```

**Edit 12/12/2018:**

The `imGui.drawFrame()` in the code above is now irrelevant, I changed the gui from ImGui to Nuklear,  and completely rewrote the gui pipeline. Unfortunately, the same problem appears.
However, I'm still using a `vkCmdDrawIndexed` to draw it.

Comment: Any complains from Validation Layers?

Comment: No, but I only activated VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation. Maybe it's not enough ?

Comment: Should suffice. It contains multiple other layers which catch common mistakes. Are You sure layers are working properly? If You make some mistake on purpose, is it caught by validation layers?

Comment: Yes, I receive validation errors. I just got one few minutes ago. But no errors anymore.

Comment: Than this indeed looks like a synchronization problem. How do You submit command buffers? And, this should be caught by validation layers, but I'll ask nevertheless - does You swapchain support transfer_dst usage?

Comment: Have you stepped through the code to verify that `imDrawData.getCmdListsCount()` is non-zero for every command buffer?

Comment: I just tried: no problem about that, there are something to draw in every CommandBuffer. 
I should have said that the blink is not regular at all in fact. The render could be perfect during few seconds, but sooner or later, the gui will randomly blink. That's why I though that the copyPixelBufferToFB override the draw of the GUI, but maybe not at all...

Comment: @Ekzuzy Yes, the transfer_dst usage is set. About how I submit the render command buffer, I edited my post.

Comment: Did you resolve the issue? I wonder if this is a valid route for video playback, without the tons of Vulkan boilerplate.